# Magento Pass Value to block function

Tags: magento

Hi how to pass value from phtml to block?

Below is my code:
store.php

```
public function __construct($type1) 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $items = Mage::getModel('redemption/store')->getCollection()
               ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
               ->addFieldToFilter('category', array('eq' => $type1))
               ->addAttributeToSort('mreward_required', 'asc');
        $this ->setCollection($items);

    }
```

index.phtml

```
$type1 = 'Celcom';
$items = $this->getCollection($type1);
```

It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to parse something from phtml to the block? phtml is only a html code which all the datas will be parsed by the block. But, if you still want to do so (I think it's very weird), you can try something like :

On your phtml :

```
$type = 'type';
$this->setType($type);

//call a function so the block can get the type
$this->parseTheDataToBlock();
```

And on your block :

```
public function parseTheDataToBlock() {
    //you will get the type here (from the phtml) 
    var_dump($this->getType());
}
```

Comment: I want to do this because I want to call out the redemption products base on category. It is better ways to do that?

Comment: If you want to do that, you can call `$this->getCollection($type)` and redefined `getCollection` function on the block `public function getCollection($type) {}`.